# Postgres: Select all fields where json field array contains a particular value?

Tags: json, postgresql

Let say I have a `users` and `companies` table, where 1 user can work for multiple companies. In this case I model it using JSON field.

```
users
- id: PK
- jobs: json
```

Sample `jobs` field: `[{"company_id": 1, "title": "Engineer" }, {"company_id": 2, "title": "Accountant"}]`

Given a company ID, is there a way to run 1 SQL query (Postgres 9.4) that can extract all the user IDs that have worked in that company? Something like:

`select id from users where map(jobs, "company_id") contains <?>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might not be the best way to do it, but this works:

```
SELECT id FROM
  (SELECT id, json_array_elements(jobs) as a FROM table) b
WHERE a->>'company_id'='1';
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. I'm accepting this because this works for `json` field type too. The other answer by @jgm works too, but it requires your field to be `jsonb`.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE jobs @>'[{"company_id":1}]'
```

Comment: Just a note: using this requires the `jsonb` datatype, will not work with `json`

Comment: True but if you're on 9.4 you really should be using jsonb unless you have a specific requirement which precludes it.

Comment: Yes, that's why just a note. And of course for one-off performance-insensitive queries one can always cast json into jsonb.